# sqlalchemy COUNT and IF

Tags: count, sqlalchemy

anyone know how can i do counting if in SQL alchemy like

```
COUN(IF(table_row = 1 AND table_row2 =2),1,0)
```

i make something like this,

```
func.COUNT(func.IF((TransactionMessage.tm_read==0 and TransactionMessage.tm_type==1),1,0)).label('t_message_count'),
```

But sqlalchemy make 2 seperate  if with TransactionMesssage.tm_read,
and TransactinMessage.tm_type

Could somone help me to resolve problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I do not have environment to test, but most probably you need to use [sqlalchemy.sql.expression.and_](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/reference/sqlalchemy/expressions.html?highlight=and_#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.and_) expression:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import and_
...
func.COUNT(func.IF(and_(TransactionMessage.tm_read == 0, 
                        TransactionMessage.tm_type == 1), 1, 0)
           ).label('t_message_count'),
```

Comment: Thanks for this. it is undocumented in SQLAlchemy site.